# Conjugates of a normal subgroup of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and $B$ a normal subgroup of $A$.

I know that $B^g\le A^g=A$, namely the conjugates of $B$ in $G$ are still in $A$. But when I went further, I got stuck.

Are the conjugates of $B$ in $G$ still normal subgroups of $A$? In other words, my question is: if $B\trianglelefteq A\trianglelefteq G$, can we have $B^g\trianglelefteq A$ for all $g\in G$?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for your reply. But I may not think that answers my question, because I was not asking if a subnormal subgroup in $G$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: You're welcome and you're right. That's why I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *Yes*. In the following, fix a $g\in G$.

$B^g$ is normal in $A$ if and only if for every $b^g\in B^g$ and $a\in A$ holds $(b^g)^a\in B^g$.
Since $A$ is normal in $G$, there is an $\bar a\in A$ so that $ag=g \bar a$ (basically, $\bar a=a^{g^{-1}}$, which I do not use for notational reasons). It follows

$$(b^g)^a=agbg^{-1}a^{-1}=(ag)b(ag)^{-1} = (g\bar a)b(g\bar a)^{-1}=g\bar a b \bar a^{-1}g^{-1} = (b^{\bar a})^g.$$

Since $B$ is normal in $A$, we have $b^{\bar a}\in B$ which shows that $(b^{\bar a})^g\in B^g$.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question perfectly! By the way, I think I found a typo and I’ve corrected it.

Comment: @Math Thank your for your edit. Unfortunately, I had to reject it since I reworked the complete notation in the answer. Maybe check whether you still find the typo and correct it again, or, if you dislike this answer, I rewind to the previous one.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for your answer!